# How to get 401 response from identityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Recently we have started to use IdentiyServer 4 (which is great!).
We have one Identity service which all other services are using, usually with JWT.
The problem is that in cases the token is not valid (expired or simply wrong) instead of getting 401 response (un authorised) we simply get 500 (internal server error).

Am I doing something wrong?
I even tried to use their official code sample as our identity service and ended up with the same result.

Here is Startup.cs relevant lines:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters();
```

Configure:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = Configuration["URLs:IdentityServer"],
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "api1"
});
```

Here is the Exception:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.d__14.MoveNext()

(There is more but I don't think it's relevant)

Comment: 500 means uncaught exception. Look at the logs to see what is actually happening

Comment: I know what 500 means, the problem is that the JWT is wrong and I need to issue new one. Question is why I'm not getting 401?

Comment: Again, because there's some exception being thrown. Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: Please actually check your logs. There should be an error somewhere which you can catch.

Comment: Thanks all, added the exception and stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It seems I used old version of IdentityServer4. Upgraded to the latest (2.6.0), had to changed some configuration flow (according to the [official docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/)) and it solved the problem.